# Using Cache-Control header with react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching, react-query, cache-control

I was wondering whether `react-query` take `Cache-Control` header coming from the server into consideration.

I want to set the `staleTime` based on the instructions coming from the server about how long should the data be cached.

I went through the docs, but it seems like all the docs are related to setting it manually and hardcoding it.

Do I have to set the `staleTime` & `cacheTime` manually or can it be automated based on headers sent from server?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Query has no knowledge of response headers. It's promise based, and you can use any way you want to produce a promise. So by that definition, it cannot know about network headers.

Imo there also isn't much value in syncing these two things - they are different layers of caches that build upon each other. If you have browser caching enabled via the `Cache-Control` header, you can just as well keep `staleTime` to zero and let the background refetches trigger when necessary, because they will read from the browser cache anyways.

Comment: But in this case, even if data is in browser's cache, ReactQuery will still switch in loading state and then back to Success. 
Also if i have some resource-full transformations on response, they will still be executed(I admit that this argument is a bit off).

Usually we declare the cache time as a hardcoded value when useQuery options. Will it work if i change it after the response?